# How to monitor each of Sent SMS status?

Tags: android, sms

I developed codes to send SMS to more than one persons. But current problem is that I cannot know which person is got the message and which is sent failed. I want to know each of sent SMS status and the receiver phone number, is it can be done?

Comment: I successfully implemented this in my app.. Please check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388236/not-able-to-pass-retrieve-extras-inside-broadcast-receiver