# How to get Delivery Report of each SMS sent in loop android?

Tags: android, sms

I am working on SMS app. I need to send SMS in loop. Registered Broadcast Receiver for SENT and DELIVERED status, but problem is how to distinguish which delivery notification is for which SMS that I sent. I am using SMSMANAGER class to send SMS. My problem is similar discussed here: [How to monitor each of Sent SMS status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639778/how-to-monitor-each-of-sent-sms-status)