# Not able to catch each sms status

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

Im trying to catch the status of each sms delivery but my code is not getting it but instead the status of only one message.

Anyone can give hints?
This si my code.. This is working but I need to catch each status of each sms.

```
public void sendMultipart(String msgbody,String msg_receipients,Intent intent)
{
    BroadcastReceiver smsStatusReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
    {   
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            context.unregisterReceiver(this); //unregister receiver     
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Logger.logtoFile(tag,"RESULT_OK "+intent.getStringExtra("num"),1);
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Logger.logtoFile(tag,"RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE "+intent.getStringExtra("num"),1);
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Logger.logtoFile(tag,"RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE "+intent.getStringExtra("num"),1);
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Logger.logtoFile(tag,"RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF "+intent.getStringExtra("num"),1);
                    break;
            }
    }
};

IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("sent");
MyApplication.getAppContext().registerReceiver(smsStatusReceiver, intentFilter);
Intent intent1 = new Intent("sent");
intent1.putExtra("num", msg_receipients);
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

try
{
    ArrayList<String> messages = sms.divideMessage(msgbody); //Divide msg into chunk
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>(messages.size());
    for (int j = 0; j < messages.size(); j++)
        sentIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyApplication.getAppContext(), 0, intent1, 0));
    sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(msg_receipients, null, messages, sentIntents, null);
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
    {Logger.logtoFile(tag, "SMS sender error  "+e.toString(), 2);}
catch(Exception l)
{Logger.logtoFile(tag, l.toString(), 2);} 
}
```

Comment: Registering an anonymous BroadcastReceiver is a bad thing to do, because you're unable to unregister it later and it leads to a memory leak.

Comment: What's best is I need to create a new class for my broadcast receiver?   Can you give me example of what you are referring to?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can keep the BroadcastReceiver as a field in your class, the idea is that you should be able to call unregisterReceiver() at a later moment passing the reference to this BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: hello, I edited above code and I am able to unregister my broadcast receiver. It worked nicely on my end.

Comment: I notice that the above code is not catching the status properly of each sms when I send multiple sms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved after I modified my pending intent. Request code must be unique and also i added this PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT to cancel the current intent or you can update current intent.

```
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyApplication.getAppContext(),smsID++,intentExtra, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```